# Display ObjectId initialized from bootstrap

Tags: mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I want to bootstrap the folllowing class:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId

class Foo{  
 ObjectId id  
 String name 

}
```

Now in BootStrap.groovy I have put:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
...
def foo = new Foo(
id: new ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
name: "foo"
)
```

But when i want to inspect the scaffolding result I get the following error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

Class
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
Message
    Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.Integer] to required type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] for property 'id': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

How can I display the `ObjectId`?

Comment: Do you still have hibernate loaded?  If so, [I believe you need to add](http://grails.github.io/inconsequential/mongo/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.2%20Combining%20Mongo%20and%20Hibernate) `static mapWith = "mongo"` to your domain class

Comment: @tim_yates Here is my [BuildConfig,groovy](http://pastebin.com/4Epagm2z) and here is my [DataSource.groovy](http://pastebin.com/s2jmp3ap)

Comment: @tim_yates I have uninstalled hibernate plugin as in `2.1 Using Mongo Standalone`

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add proper mapping to your Foo class (and use assigned `String`id instead `ObjectId` type). For example:

```
class Foo{

String id
String name 

static mapping = {
    table "Foo" 
    id column: 'Id', generator: 'assigned'
    name column: "Name"
  }
}
```

And then in you Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def foo = new Foo(
    id: "507f191e810c19729de860ea",
    name: "foo"
)
foo.save();
```

Comment: I need `ObjectId` here due to mongo utilization.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with mongodb and afraid to give you a bad advice.